# Deriving a logarithmic solution for a functional equation

Tags: functions, logarithms, functional-equations

While studying a heuristic argument for the Collatz conjecture, I found the following functional equation
$$f(n)=\frac{1}{2}\left(3+f\left(\frac{1}{2}n\right)+f\left(\frac{3}{2}n\right)\right)$$
$f(n)$ behaves logarithmically, and indeed it is possible to get a solution by substituting $f(n)=a\ln(n)+b$. But is it the only solution? If so, how would one prove that it must be a logarithmic function? If not, what are all the families of solutions (using common assumptions, such as continuity)?

Comment: You get multiple solutions, because any choice for $b$ works. But then, because the functional equation only relates $x$ to rational multiples of $x$ you can partition the real numbers into equivalence classes that are all rational multiples of each other, and choose a different $b$ for each equivalence class, and the functional equation would still hold. If you added the constraint that the function has to be continuous, solutions of this type would vanish.

Comment: @ZoeAllen I know, but my question is about whether $f(n)$ only has the form $a\ln(n)+b$ or not. But what you said is an interesting point!

Comment: If you state a functional equation you should state the domain and codomain of the function, as well as the domain of the variables in the functional equation

Comment: @ordptt my point is that if you want to prove that's the only solution, you're going to have to add an extra assumption, such as continuity, because what you want to conclude doesn't follow from the assumptions you have given

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not the only solution. If $g(x)$ is solves $$g(x)-2g(2x)+g(3x)=0\tag{*}$$ and $f(x)$ solves your equation, then $f(x)+g(x)$ also solves your equation. This works also in the other direction: if $f_1(x)$, $f_2(x)$ are two solutions of your equation, then $g(x)=f_1(x)-f_2(x)$ must satisfy $(*)$.

So you might want to focus on solving $(*)$ instead, but as an example notice that linear functions $g(x)=bx+c$ are some of its solutions. Combining with $f(x)=a\ln x$ you have found (where necessarily $a=3/(2\ln 2-\ln 3)$), we get another family of solutions is $f(x)=a\ln x+bx+c$ for any $b,c$ constants.

It is possible there are other solutions, but this is enough to disprove that logarithm is the only one.

**Note:** As noted in comments, there will be many solutions unless additional assumptions are imposed, such as continuity. As a simple discontinuous example consider
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
a \ln x & x=2^u3^v \text{ for some }u,v\in\mathbb{Z}\\
a \ln x +x& x=2^u3^v\pi \text{ for some }u,v\in\mathbb{Z}\\
a \ln x +x+1& \text{else}\\
\end{cases}
$$
You can verify it satisfies the equation, more wild examples are possible of course.